# WPF: Show listview group collapsed by default

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a listview items grouped by purchaseorder number. When the user opens the page they want to see items collapsed (now it shows expanded). Also, they want to expand any line item that they prefer.

```
        ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(EncumbranceEntriesList.ItemsSource);

        if (dataView != null && dataView.SortDescriptions.Count == 0)
        {
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder.DisplayNumber", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PurchaseOrderDetail.TransactionDate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("EntryDate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

            EncumbranceEntriesList.Group("PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder.DisplayNumber");

        }
```

------xaml----

```
    <abc:DetailsListView x:Name="EncumbranceEntriesList" Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentEncumbranceJournalEntries}"
            SelectionMode="Extended" ShowGroupItemCount="True"
            IsSortingEnabled="False"
            abc:ListBoxExtensions.HasBindableSelectedItems="True">

<ListView.View>
                <abc:DetailsView>
                    <abc:DetailsViewColumn Header="PO #" Width="100"
                        IsInitiallyVisible="False" IsUserHidable="False"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder.DisplayNumber}"
                        SortPropertyName="PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder.DisplayNumber"
                        GroupPropertyName="PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder.DisplayNumber"/>
                    <abc:DetailsViewColumn Header="Line Item" Width="200"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PurchaseOrderDetail.ShortItemDescription}"/>
                    <abc:DetailsViewColumn Header="Encumbrance Date" Width="120"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EntryDate, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}"
                        SortPropertyName="EntryDate" DefaultSortDirection="Descending"/>

                              </abc:DetailsView>
            </ListView.View>
        </abc:DetailsListView>
```

Comment: By collapsed I meant,by default user need to see just line items with header details (Purchase Order number and count)only.When the expand the line item they need to see details under it.

Comment: Assuming that abc:DetailsViewColumn is your own code add a dependency property to called is expanded. If it is false  set visibility to collapsed.

Comment: Other option would be to use a data grid, which supports details view out of the box. It also has a property to collapse all of the detail rows.

Comment: Thank you so much  joshwl2003